# Change LDAP domain after checking username

Tags: c#, authentication, ldap

I have a login page where I need user to login without knowing the domain in which the user exists by checking username.

```
 String adPath = "LDAP://domain";
 LdapAuthentication adAuth = new LdapAuthentication(adPath);
 if (true == adAuth.IsAuthenticated(domain, username, Password))
 { 
  // something to do
 }
```

How can I change the domain path dynamically according to user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a condition to change adAuth after checking username

```
 string adPath = "LDAP://domain";
 string anotheradPath = "LDAP://seconddomain";

 if (username== "something" )
    {
        adAuth = new LdapAuthentication(adPath );
    }
 else
    {
         adAuth = new LdapAuthentication(anotheradPath );
    }
```